# Does the series $1+3t+5t^2+7t^3+ \cdots$ have a closed formula?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Does the series $f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (2i-1)t^{i-1}=1+3t+5t^2+7t^3+ \cdots$ have a closed formula?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @BarryCipra, yes, thank you very much. I will edit the equation.

Answer (score 6):

let $t = x^2,$ you now have
$$ 1+3x^2 + 5 x^4 + 7 x^6 \cdots $$
which is an evident derivative

It is prudent to confirm the final result, see comment below, as the substitution is not a bijection. It does work out fine, either by computer or fiddling with geometric series

```
? taylor( (1+t) /  (1-t)^2 , t )
%3 = 1 + 3*t + 5*t^2 + 7*t^3 + 9*t^4 + 11*t^5 + 13*t^6 + 15*t^7 + 17*t^8 + 19*t^9 + 21*t^10 + 23*t^11 + 25*t^12 + 27*t^13 + 29*t^14 + 31*t^15 + O(t^16)
```

Comment: This substitution gives the result $\frac{1+t}{(1-t)^2}$ as the closed form. Also the series only converges for $ |t| \lt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (2i-1)\,t^{i-1}=2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i\,t^{i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} t^{i-1}=2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i\,t^{i-1}-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} t^{i}$$

$$f(t)=2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} t^{i} \right)'-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} t^{i}\right)=\frac{2}{(1-t)^2}-\frac{1}{1-t}=\frac{1+t}{(1-t)^2}$$